# Adding condition of giving a url to the original work to MIT license

Tags: mit

I wand to share my code under MIT license on github, my question is: can I add a condition to the license that makes anyone who uses my code include copyright notice along with a url to my original work on github so that other people find it easy to get a licensed copy of this code?

Answer (score 2):

The copyright notice is already protected by the license:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Therefore you can achieve the desired effect, without modifying the license itself, by just adding your URL to the copyright notice.

Something like `Copyright © 2020 Your Name (your-url.xyz)` should be sufficient to ensure that anyone who reads the license can easily find your repository.